# CodeIgniter: Unknown column xxx in ‘where clause’

Tags: activerecord, codeigniter

I am working on a bug(?) for a few hours now, but couln’t fix it.

This is my code:

```
 if(!$this->db->get_where('merken',array('m_merken' => $brand))->count_all_results()){

      $insetData = array('m_name' => $brand);
      $this->db->insert('merken', $insetData);

 }
```

$brand contains ‘Acer’ in this preview.

```
 A Database Error Occurred

    Error Number: 1054

    Unknown column ‘Acer’ in ‘where clause’

    SELECT * FROM (`merken`) WHERE `m_name` = Acer
```

I want to check if it already exists, but it won’t work very well.

Comment: I see my typo 'm_merken', has to be 'm_name', but still an error. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without quotes, your statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (`merken`) WHERE `m_name` = Acer
```

`Acer` refers to a column-name. If your intent is a string literal, put it in single-quotes, as in:

```
SELECT * FROM (`merken`) WHERE `m_name` = 'Acer'
```

Also, as a matter of good programming practice, avoid `SELECT *`, better to `SELECT` each column you want to return, even if the list is lengthy.

-- EDIT --

I suspect I'm missing the point... the SQL is generated. Two things to check:

Is `m_name` correctly declared as a `string/varchar/char` field?
Failing that, try literally setting the brand name to `'Acer'`, with the quote marks. I doubt this is a reasonable solution, though.

Comment: The m_name is declarated as a varchar(255), i've try this code too:

 if($this->db->get_where("merken",array("name" => '$brand'))->count_all_results() == 0){
                                     
                    $insetData = array("name" => '$brand');
                    $this->db->insert("merken", $insetData);
                    
                    echo "succes";
                    
                }else{

                    echo "already exists";

               }

But when I try that nothing returns, so there is something wrong but don't know what. No error and no succes/exists.

Comment: if($this->db->get_where("merken",array("name" => $brand))->count_all_results() == 0){
                                   
                    $insetData = array("name" => $brand);
                    $this->db->insert("merken", $insetData);

echo "gelukt";
                    
                }else{

 echo "bestaat al?";

                }

Comment: It's seems to work now, thanks! The singe-quotes and change the name m_name to 'name' (in the code and Database) has worked. 

Thanks for your time!